# modify dom in page through a chrome extentsion

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to create an chrome extension containing the following features:

1 When user visit pages of a certain domain this extension will remove some doms in the page.

2 Check the size of all the images, if one of them have a larger size than specified, then this image will be set to the specified size, when user click it , the image will resize to its original dimension.

Now this is what I have done:

```
"content_scripts": [
    {
        "matches": ["http://*.xx.com/*"],
        "js": ["res/js/jquery-2.0.3.min.js", "res/js/inject.js"],
        "run_at": "document_end"
    }
]
```

inject.js:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("xxx").remove();
    $("img").each(....);
});
```

However I meet some problems:

1 The jquery library is referred locally, is there any idea to load the jquery from a CDN source?

2 It take a long time before the page loaded completely,which means that the content to be removed will keep visible for a long time.

3 The page use the twitter-like layout, when user scroll the page, more content will be loaded. So the problem comes.

My `inject.js` will run once the page load complete, all images already loaded will be processed. But when more content are loaded, the new loaded images will be not processed.

So I wonder if there is some event like `element_rendered` I can captured? If yes, I can make my job like this:

```
xxx.events.addListener('element_rendered',function(ele){
    if(shouldRemvoed(ele)){
        //remvoe it.
    } else if(isImg){
        //check size......
    }
});
```

Is this possible,or is there an alternative to do my job?

Answer (score 0):

> 1 The jquery library is referred locally, is there any idea to load
> the jquery from a CDN source?

No, not in chrome extension

> 2 It take a long time before the page loaded completely,which means that the content to be >removed will keep visible for a long time.
>
> 3 The page use the twitter-like layout, when user scroll the page, more content will be >loaded. So the problem comes.

You can use [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) to track changes on the DOM.